# c++ const not working with header file prototypes - redeclaration or no prototype errors

Tags: c++

I'm learning C++ and I'm trying to understand const. I've been using const with my getters and display functions to keep values from changing when getting and sending to display.

I'm working on a program that uses several header and .cpp files and I didn't have any issues with const until this part of the program:

This part of the program gathers information for a product. It has 3 display options. All 3 displays have been set to const and I have no errors there.

In my header file, I have these 2 prototypes:

```
float getShippingCost() const{return shippingCost;}
float getTotalPrice()   const{return totalPrice;}
```

In the same file I have other getters and setters, none of which appear to have errors and most of the getters are const.

In my .cpp file I have the methods:

```
float Product :: getShippingCost() {
    insert code here, proven to work before I started working with
    const and other files, the return as shown earlier is in the .h file, 
    the same is true for the next method.}

float Product :: getTotalCost(){insert code here}
```

If I set the methods in the .cpp file I get a re-declaration error. If I remove the const I get a no prototype found in the .h error. I've tried everything I can think of including moving the return to the .cpp file.

Can someone please explain how this works? I thought I was understanding this, but now I'm just confused.

My code is as below:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std; 
class Wallet 
{ 
private: 
    float money; 
    float dollars; 
    float cents; 
public: 
    float getMoney() const {return money;}
    void display()const; 
}; 

float Wallet::getMoney() const { money += dollars + cents; } 

void Wallet::display() const { cout << "You have $" << money << endl; }
```

Comment: Sorry I mean set the methods in the .cpp file to const in the second to last paragraph 1st line.

Comment: Please post actual code - for instance, why does your prototype have a body? (BTW, you can edit your own question)

Comment: Can you share a [mcve]

Comment: This Redeclaration Error post might help:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28534809/redeclaration-error

Comment: Thank you for that link, it doesn't really address my problem though. I was trying to cut some of the code for brevity, but I'll post more in a few seconds.

Comment: Actually I just realized I can't post the full code. I'm only asking for an explanation because this is an assignment, I don't think I can post the full code. I'm just trying to understand how to use const between a header file and a .cpp file or between a class public prototype and the method that uses it.

Comment: You could 'transform' it just so that we can reproduce your problem and help you? - Help Us To Help You?

Comment: Working on doing that.

Comment: #include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

class Wallet
{
 private:
 float money;
 float dollars;
 float cents;

 public:
 float getMoney() const {return money;}
 void display()const; 
};

float Wallet :: getMoney() const
{
 money += dollars + cents;
}

void Wallet :: display() const
{
 cout << "You have $" << money << endl;
}

Comment: Okay...that's not pasting well

Comment: Yuo, you have two implementations, check answers below.

Answer (score 2):

Without the minimal example from and from the explanation, In your header file you say you have:

```
float getShippingCost() const{return shippingCost;}
```

Is not a declaration, its a declaration and implementation.

`float getShippingCost() const;` is a declaration only

And in your .cpp you mention you have:

```
float Product:: getShippingCost() const{insert code here}
```

Which is another implementation. Its not a problem with `const` it is what it says it is a re declaration. To fix this you change your header to only contain

```
float getShippingCost() const;
float getTotalPrice() const;
```

Comment: I've tried that as well and received the same error. I'm still trying to add an example of the code somewhere, but let me try that again first.

Comment: It actually worked this time. I'm not sure why as I've tried it more than once so I must have missed something before. So my question then is why can you sometimes return in the prototype and other times you can't? I'm trying to post code, but the editor won't allow me too.

Comment: For completeness, I will add your code myself by editing the post. Second its not `okay` to add code to prototype it has to be in one place either or. Its usually done because with getters/setters it makes it neat. However if you have defined it in your header you dont need it in the cpp and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

This is going off from what my understanding is of your question. it's more helpful to post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we know exactly what you're working with.

When you declare a member function with the `const` keyword, you must use it in both the declaration and the definition like so:

In the header .h:

```
class Product {
    float getTotalCost() const;

    float m_cost;
}
```

In the source .cpp:

```
Product::getTotalCost() const // <- remember to add the keyword in both
{
    return m_cost;
}
```

Just as an aside, you should NEVER EVER use floating point numbers for finance! Either used a fixed point decimal class or an integer and divide.

Comment: Cinder, thank you for that tip. Can you please explain why it's a bad thing or point me to a good article about it?

Comment: Floating point number cannot accurately represent the base 10 multiples we use for money. The problem with floats and doubles is that the vast majority of money-like numbers don't have an exact representation as a integer times a power of two. In fact, the only fractions of a hundred between 0/100 and 100/100 (which are significant when dealing with money because they're integer cents) that can be represented exactly as an IEEE-754 binary floating-point number are 0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75 and 1. All the others are off by a small amount.

Comment: How a floating point number works is dedicates a bit for the sign, a few bits to store an exponent for the base, and the rest for a multiple of that elevated base. This leads to numbers like 10.25 being represented in a form similar to 1025 * 10-2; except that instead of the base being 10, for floats and doubles, it's two, so that would be 164 * 2-4.